# Positioning a Video in Dreamweaver

Tags: css, video, positioning, dreamweaver

I have a video that I am trying to position over a section on a website. On my test server the position is perfect but when I upload my new file to the online server the video stays centered and below all the other info on the site. How do I code this so the index1 file displays the video like my test server.

The code on my test server is:

```
<div class="#main_video" id="main_video">
   <video width="460" height="260" controls>
      <source src="include/promo_2012.ogv" type="video/ogg">
      <source src="include/promo_2012.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</div>
```

I selected the div and positioned it at:

```
Relative<br/>
Top: -414<br/>
Left: -266
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
#main_video{
    float:left;
}
```

This should put it to the left. Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/S6mmD/

And by the way, classes are used in HTML like so: `<div class='red'>` and in CSS: `.red{color:#f00;}`

ids are styled in CSS with the pound sign `#` like above.

Comment: I want to get rid of the centering. It should be aligned over to the left and up slightly from the bottom. I tried to attach images but this site didn't allow me to.

Comment: Ah! That's where I went wrong. Thanks for your help. I forgot to edit the CSS file (I'm new to this haha). Thanks for looking into this I really appreciate it!

Comment: One last question. I can't seem to get the video to stay aligned with the rest of the body of the site: URL is: http://www.firstimeonline.com/index1.php

Any tips?

Comment: You should nest the div for the video inside the content div. Don't forget to mark correct answers.